# I'm having trouble with a codeabbey assignment, just need a push on how to start

Tags: java

I don't want the answer, I just don't understand how to scan the first number to tell the program how many pairs there are. If you could nudge me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

"Most programs should be able to make some choices and decisions. And we are going to practice conditional programming now.
This is usually done by a kind of if ... else statements which may look like:

IF some_condition THEN
    do_something
ELSE
    do_other_thing
ENDIF
Depending on your programming language syntax could be different and else part is almost always optional. You can read more in wikipedia article on Conditional statements.

Of two numbers, please, select one with minimum value. Here are several pairs of numbers for thorough testing.

Input data will contain number of test-cases in the first line.
Following lines will contain a pair of numbers to compare each.
For Answer please enter the same amount of minimums separated by space, for example:

data:
3
5 3
2 8
100 15

answer:
3 2 15 "

Comment: Try using the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class. Here's a tutorial: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/ndale/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you might want to format your example data a bit. I understood it, but mostly only because I've seen that question format before.

Well, to answer your question but not the question's question (heh), note this:

> Following lines will contain a pair of numbers to compare each.

Note the "lines" (plural) and the "each." We're going to need a loop.
We also know each line is a test case.
So modify the instructions:

> Loop over the following test cases, comparing each pair

But how many times do we loop?

> Input data will contain number of test-cases in the first line

That's the first number.

So here's our code skeleton:

```
//We can use a Scanner for convenience, it has a readInt() method
Scanner input = new Scanner(/*your input*/);

int numCases = input.readInt();

for(int i = 0; i < numCases; i++) {
    int first = input.readInt(); //readInt() will also skip newlines, just a tip.
    int second = input.readInt();
    /* Compare two inputs, do stuff*/
}
```

For the record, you could also simply ignore the first input and just loop until there is no more input, but that's sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a `Scanner`. If you're reading from the console, then this will work:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

If you need to read from a file, then you can add this line as well.

```
System.setIn(new FileInputStream("inputFileName"));
```

For your specific case, you can do something like:

```
int numPairs = scan.nextInt();
```

You can find out more about `Scanner` and its methods from the Oracle documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).